# Symfony - AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator problem

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I am building a very simple login page using Symfony framework.
I added

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
```

and called it as:

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
```

in my LoginFormAuthenticator.php but when I go to localhost, it says :

**Attempted to load class "AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?**

What can be a problem here knowing that I called right class from right namespace, as it is declared in Symfony documentation?

Thank you in advance.

I expected to view my login page as everything is done regarding to Symfony documentation. Instead of that I am getting very bad error.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K1hO.png)

Comment: All seems good, have you try to clear your cache ?

Comment: @YohannDanielCarter Yes, but nothing happened. All the same.

Comment: Hello. There is very little data on the problem.
The instruction is simple https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security/form_login_setup.html
Did PHP Bin/Console Cache: Clear help?

Comment: @kubarik Tried to clear cache with a given method, but the result in console is: 2022-12-07T11:21:55+00:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator" not found

Comment: @NovicaVojinovic in composser there is an entry about symfony/security-bundle

Comment: @kubarik Nothing. Run composer require symfony/security-bundle, got:
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
[critical] Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator" not found
!!  
Script auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Comment: @NovicaVojinovic Symphony version, installed package symfony/security-bundle version?

Comment: @kubarik Yes, entered code composer require symfony/security-bundle
Got:
Executing script cache:clear [KO] [KO] Script cache:clear returned with error code 255 [critical] Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator" not found !! Script auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Comment: @NovicaVojinovic https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42170

Answer (score 0):

You have extended not the good one class.

You should extend **this** one AbstractAuthenticator:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;
```

**Not this:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authenticator.html